# Spring cloud kubernetes all dependency

Tags: kubernetes

Converting a docker POC to a kubernetes project and based on Spring documentation (https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-kubernetes), I tried to add a spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all maven dependency and keep getting version not defined though I added spring-cloud dependency pom. Upon checking, found the "all" starter dependency is applicable for kubernetes client (spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all) and not to include entire spring cloud kubernetes starter dependencies (spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all). The spring cloud I am using is 2021.0.3. Am I missing anything or there are some other gap in the documentation?

Comment: [Spring Cloud Kubernetes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/) provides several nice-to-haves, like reading properties directly from ConfigMaps and querying Services to populate client-side load balancers, but it's not required.  Can you run your existing Docker image as-is?  What's in your `pom.xml` and what's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I was getting the error from maven as "Version not defined for the dependency" since the spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all wasn't part of the BOM. Anyhow, i used client-all and able to do discovery. Thanks